# Frame and Itemize together

Tags: environments

I want to redefine `frame` as `frame + itemize`. I've so far tried this -

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{myframe}{\begin{frame}\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}
\item
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

What exactly is wrong in this and then how to correctly redefine this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beamer` environment `frame` collects its body using the following technique: it reads and stores tokens following `\begin{frame}` looking for `\end{frame}` without expanding them except in one case (see below), but it will accept an `\end{frame}` as the end of the environment body being collected only if it has seen the same number of `\begin{...}` as `\end{...}` during this collection process (it does not try to match them). This is what `\beamer@begin@stack` is used for in `\beamer@collect@@body` from `beamerbaseframe.sty`.

In case the stack is empty (i.e., it has seen as many `\end{...}` as `\begin{...}` after `\begin{frame}`) and the following `\end{...}` is not an `\end{frame}`, it expands this `\end` hoping this will make `\end{frame}` appear.<sup>1</sup> But this **only** happens under the condition I gave (as many `\end{...}` as `\begin{...}` after the initial `\begin{frame}` must have been seen).

In your example, the `\begin{itemize}` pushes one `b` (i.e., opens one level) to the `\beamer@begin@stack` stack. This `b` is popped when `\end{myframe}` is read. At this point, `\beamer@collect@@body` knows it has seen as many `\begin{...}` as `\end{...}` after the `\begin{frame}`. This is true but misleading, since if `\end{myframe}` were expanded, it would yield two pops. So, `\beamer@begin@stack` thinks that the next `\end{...}` must provide `\end{frame}`, possibly after expanding the `\end...` token (see footnote 1). Alas, this is incorrect; the next `\end{...}` is `\end{document}`. `\enddocument` is thus expanded, then `\beamer@collect@@body` continues to look for `\end{frame}` but of course never finds it, reaches the end of the file, which triggers the error:

```latex
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

So, basically, the problem is that `\beamer@collect@@body` can't keep a proper count of the `\end{...}` because your `\end{myframe}` hides two of these (`\end{itemize}\end{frame}`) and `\beamer@collect@@body` will not discover them via expansion of `\endmyframe` despite the presence of `\end{myframe}`, because it has seen more `\begin{...}` than `\end{...}` at the point where it sees this `\end{myframe}` (non-empty stack due to the `\begin{itemize}`).

The solutions require you not to hide `\end{...}` in macros that `\beamer@collect@@body` is not going to expand. One is using the `environ` package as in [ferahfeza's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503079/73317), another is using `\itemize` and `\enditemize` as follows (neither of them affect the `\beamer@begin@stack` stack, therefore when `\beamer@collect@@body` sees `\end{myframe}`, the stack is empty, thus `\endmyframe` is expanded once, which makes the `\end{frame}` visible to the environment body scanning process):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment*{myframe}[1]
  {\begin{frame}{#1}%
   \begingroup\itemize}
  {\enditemize\endgroup
   \end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}{Frame title}
\item An item
\item Another item
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Footnote**

1. More precisely, what happens is the following (in `beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55`). If:

   - the `\beamer@begin@stack` stack is empty (as many `\end{...}` as `\begin{...}` have been seen after the `\begin{frame}` whose body is being collected) and
   - the next `\end{...}` is not an `\end{frame}`—let's say it is an `\end{foobar}`,

   then `\beamer@collect@@body` substitutes the first-level expansion of `\endfoobar\endgroup` for this `\end{foobar}` in the collected material. This is similar to what expanding `\end{foobar}` would produce, though the latter would do a few more things (see `source2e.pdf` p. 272):

   - check that the replacement text of `\@currenvir` is `foobar` (this would fail in the `beamer` `frame` body collection process we are talking about, as `\@currenvir` is `frame`);
   - honor a previous `\@endparenv` command (used to suppress paragraph indentation at the beginning of text following some paragraph-making environments, unless said text is preceded by a blank line or by `\par`);
   - honor a previous `\ignorespacesafterend` command (used to make the next `\end{...}` ignore the spaces that may follow it).

Comment: Great! This doesn't require additional use of a package, so loved this one. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any way to add the argument `\begin{frame}{frame-title}` in this code? With the `environ` package @ferahfeza managed to incorporate it too, but I think it would be better to do it without the help of packages.

Comment: Sure, please see the last edit. If desired, one could add a star variant, optional arguments, arbitrary delimited arguments, whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Using package `environ`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}{#1}
\begin{itemize}
\BODY
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}
\item First
\item Second
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just have one question, why those arguments are necessary? I removed them and compiled, still got the same result. Is there any special function associated with them?

Comment: (I mean \NewEnviron{myframe}[1][] these two arguments)

Comment: It is for title of frame; `\begin{myframe}[Title of frame]`.

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks. One more doubt, what was wrong with my code? Why it did not work?

Comment: I am sorry but that argument is not working for the frame-title. I'm getting errors. I added something like `\begin{myframe}{Niranjan}`

Comment: Not `{}`, it is `[]`, `\begin{myframe}[Niranjan]`

Comment: Oh! I made a silly mistake, thanks, this is perfectly working.