# Linear overlay in a custom environment

Tags: beamer, overlays

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503085/174620) nice solution helped me to get two environments together, but as I used this code, more and more errors occurred. I want linear overlay using the same environment. Please see this example -

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\newenvironment*{myframe}[1][]%
{\begin{frame}{#1}%
    \begingroup\itemize}
{\enditemize\endgroup
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}{TEXT TEXT TEXT}
\item<1-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\begin{enumerate}
    \item<2-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<3-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<4-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{enumerate}
\item<5-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand what these errors are and why they are occurring. I want this overlay to work in the same environment. What can be done to obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `myframe` definition expects an optional argument

```
\newenvironment*{myframe}[1][]
```

The optional argument, if not present, defaults to nothing. However, since you specify a mandatory argument in your use of `myframe`

```
\begin{myframe}{TEXT TEXT TEXT}
```

the argument is placed at the beginning of the regular `frame`, which falls inside an `\itemize`. And, since you haven't used `\item` - lists can only start with an `\item` - you receive an error that points to "perhaps a missing `\item`".

The fix here is to require a mandatory argument for `myframe` via

```
\newenvironment*{myframe}[1]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment*{myframe}[1]
  {\begin{frame}{#1}%
      \begingroup\itemize}
  {\enditemize\endgroup
  \end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}{TEXT TEXT TEXT}
  \item<1-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<2-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<3-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<4-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
  \end{enumerate}
  \item<5-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myframe}[1]%
{\begin{frame}{#1}%
    \begin{itemize}
    \BODY
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}{TEXT TEXT TEXT}
\item<1-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\begin{enumerate}
    \item<2-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<3-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
    \item<4-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{enumerate}
\item<5-> TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```